# VMware Thinapp computer name

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, thin-client, vmware-view, vmware-thinapp

We are using Thinapp in conjunction with VMware View.  This means the computer name will most likely change for a user every they log in since our pool is about 1000 desktops (View1, View2, View3 to 1000).  I have an application that we are pushing out successfully however there is a registration that has to take place when you launch the app on a different computer.  Registration is tied to the computer name and to register its as simple as putting in your username and pressing register, but I would really like to bypass this step for my users.  It doesn't violate any licensing or software agreements (I've already checked with the vendor).  My question is can I assign the sandbox or package a "computer name" that the Thinapp will look at and it will remain the same (ie appdesktop1) instead of looking at the windows computer name (ie View1, View2 etc)?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible.

You might want to ask your vendor if there is a way to bypass the registration during the the application start or see what the the registration piece does. If it is a matter of setting a reg key or creating a file that validates the registration piece has run, these can be packaged as part of the thinapp application.